# Can't display windows taskbar systray on second screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, taskbar, notification-area

I have access to the actual task bar, what I am missing is the systray. The sound/battery indicator/Wi-Fi/show desktop buttons. They appear on my main screen but I would like them to be on my other screens as well.

Comment: What kind of windows are you using?

Comment: As far as I'm aware neither windows version supports this out of the box. Up until Windows 8 or 10 even having the taskbar on a second screen wasn't supported.